# In the definition of Product $\sigma$ algebra while considering the triple product is $\sigma_A ×\sigma_{(B×C)}$ a sigma algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, measure-theory, definition, products

**Question:** In the definition of Product $\sigma$ algebra while considering the triple product is $\sigma_A ×\sigma_{(B×C)}$ a sigma algebra?

Meaning of Notation used

- $\sigma_A$ is a sigma algebra on a set $A$, and
- $B,C$ are two sets with the sigma algebras $\sigma_B$ and $\sigma_C$ respectively.
- Now $\sigma_{(B×C)}$ is the product sigma algebra on $B×C$.

Now my question
Is $\sigma_A \times \sigma_{(B×C)}=\{(C,D):C\in \sigma_A \text{ and } D\in \sigma_{(B×C)}\}$ a sigma algebra on $A×B×C?$

**My Guess :** My guess was No/False, because when in books consider product sigma algebra on $A×B×C$ is generated by the above given collection (which I asked whether it is sigma algebra or not). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the cross products of two $\sigma$-algebras were a $\sigma$-algebra then the union of any two rectangles in $\mathbb R^2$ would have to be the cross product of two sets in $\mathbb R$. Is that possible ? Draw picture.

Comment: Ordered pair $(C,D)$ with $C\subseteq A$ and $D\subseteq B\times C$ cannot be recognized as a subset of $A\times B\times C$ so cannot be an element of any $\sigma$-algebra on $A\times B\times C$.